# How to access S3 with profile on EC2? (sts.amazonaws.com:443 error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I have EC2 and can access S3 using `ec2-user` with:
`aws s3 ls --profile myprofile s3://`

On the same EC2 I created docker container and installed aws cli tool. Created same `~./aws/config` file with same content as on host ec2 but this command (created `ec2-user` to be consistent with host user/setup) from docker container now gives error:

```
 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
- MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=POST, url=https://sts.amazonaws.com/, headers={'Content-Type': b'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'User-Agent': b'aws-cli/1.16.190 Python/3.7.3 Linux/3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.12.180', 'X-Amz-Date': b'2019Z', 'X-Amz-Security-Token': b'1234=', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=abc/2019/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=abc', 'Content-Length': '160'}>
- MainThread - urllib3.util.retry - DEBUG - Converted retries value: False -> Retry(total=False, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0, status=None)
- MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sts.amazonaws.com:443
```

Comment: When you run `aws configure list` your profile is included in the list?

Comment: Getting ```aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************DMWE         iam-role
secret_key     ****************seFy         iam-role
    region                us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config```

Comment: assign role to ec2 instance,

Comment: @Adiii - Role is assigned. If is not assigned - initial connection to S3 from EC2 would NOT work. This is a problem with docker only.